# C# Append PDF file to MemoryStream - Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, itext, memorystream

Is it possible to append an existing PDF file to a dynamically created PDF using iTextSharp? I have attempted as per my code below using PdfCopy, but I am getting a `Cannot access a closed Stream` error.

I've seen examples merging actual PDF files together, but I am not storing the finished PDFs, simply outputting the MemoryStream to a FilestreamResult:

```
private readonly float _spacingBefore = 3f;

private readonly float _spacingAfter = 3f;

private readonly float _totalWidth = PageSize.A4.Width - 80;

public MemoryStream CreateMemoryStream()
{
    var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);

    var workStream = new MemoryStream();

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);

    var pdfCopy = new PdfCopy(document, workStream);

    document.Open();

    var pdfPTable = new PdfPTable(1)
    {
        TotalWidth = _totalWidth,
        LockedWidth = true,
        SpacingBefore = _spacingBefore,
        SpacingAfter = _spacingAfter
    };

    float[] widths = { 272f };

    pdfPTable.SetWidths(widths);

    var image = Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\Images\\Logo.png"));
    image.ScaleToFit(125f, 125f);
    image.Alignment = Image.RIGHT_ALIGN;

    var pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(image)
    {
        Border = 0,
        HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
    };

    pdfPTable.AddCell(pdfPCell);

    document.Add(pdfPTable);

    pdfCopy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Documents/Test.pdf")));

    if (document != null)
    {
        document.Close();
    }

    var file = workStream.ToArray();

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    memoryStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return memoryStream;
}

public FileStreamResult Pdf(int id)
{
    var memoryStream = CreateMemoryStream();

    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + id + ".pdf");

    return File(memoryStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

I've also tried the following instead of `pdfCopy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Documents/Test.pdf")));`

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Documents/Test.pdf"));

var numberOfPages = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPages;)
{
    pdfCopy.AddPage(pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, ++i));
}
```

No matter what approach I still get a `Cannot access a closed Stream` error.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: I have this piece of code in my git https://github.com/fals/codingfirst/blob/master/random/GeradorPDFService.cs that merge files. I also notice that you are using the same instance of stream for PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);

Comment: I am trying to create a PDF in memory, once the initial document has been created I am wishing to append an actual PDF to the end of the dynamically created PDF, then present the concatenated result to browser.

Comment: Yeap I notice, what the code from my github does is the same as yours, in memory, everything, I create multiple documents, and append then insedi the loop, you can do the same.

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at your code, the good news is that the error has gone, I do get a PDF, but its just the attached PDF not the dynamic one and then the attached one. I tried also using `document.Add(pdfPTable); document.NewPage(); pdfCopy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Documents/Test.pdf")));` but still no joy. If I comment out `pdfCopy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("("/Documents/Test.pdf")));` I get an error `The document has no pages`.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a solution to my issue, I hope it proves useful to others:

```
public MemoryStream CreateMemoryStream()
{
    byte[] dynamicPdfBytes;

    using (var dynamicPDfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30))
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, dynamicPDfMemoryStream);

            document.Open();

            var pdfPTable = new PdfPTable(1)
            {
                TotalWidth = _totalWidth,
                LockedWidth = true,
                SpacingBefore = _spacingBefore,
                SpacingAfter = _spacingAfter
            };

            float[] widths = { 272f };

            pdfPTable.SetWidths(widths);

            var image = Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Images/logo.png"));
            image.ScaleToFit(125f, 125f);
            image.Alignment = Image.RIGHT_ALIGN;

            var pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(image)
            {
                Border = 0,
                HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
            };

            pdfPTable.AddCell(pdfPCell);

            document.Add(pdfPTable);
        }

        dynamicPdfBytes = dynamicPDfMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    byte[] pdfBytes;

    using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Documents/Test.pdf")))
    {
        using (var pdfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfMemoryStream);

            var acroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
            acroFields.SetField("TestField", "This is a test");
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            pdfStamper.Close();

            pdfBytes = pdfMemoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    var files = new List<byte[]> { dynamicPdfBytes, pdfBytes };

    byte[] array;

    using (var arrayMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);

        var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, arrayMemoryStream);

        document.Open();

        var directContent = pdfWriter.DirectContent;

        foreach (var bytes in files)
        {
            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(bytes);

            var numberOfPages = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;

            for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
            {
                document.NewPage();

                var page = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);

                directContent.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        document.Close();

        array = arrayMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    memoryStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return memoryStream;
}
```