# C# Add PDF Encryption to Multiple MemoryStreams - Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, pdf, encryption, itext

Is it possible to add encryption to a PDF dynamically created from multiple MemoryStreams?

Following on from my last question [C# Append PDF file to MemoryStream - Cannot access a closed Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170423/c-sharp-append-pdf-file-to-memorystream-cannot-access-a-closed-stream) I am trying to add PDF encryption.

From the example I have provided below, if the line `pdfStamper.Close();` is commented out I do not get the error `Cannot access a closed Stream`, but nor is the encryption applied to the generated PDF.

Can somebody please advise as to where I am going wrong and if possible how to achieve a solution to my problem?

```
public MemoryStream CreateMemoryStream()
{
    byte[] dynamicPdfBytes;

    using (var dynamicPDfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30))
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, dynamicPDfMemoryStream);

            document.Open();

            var pdfPTable = new PdfPTable(1)
            {
                TotalWidth = _totalWidth,
                LockedWidth = true,
                SpacingBefore = _spacingBefore,
                SpacingAfter = _spacingAfter
            };

            float[] widths = { 272f };

            pdfPTable.SetWidths(widths);

            var image = Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Images/logo.png"));
            image.ScaleToFit(125f, 125f);
            image.Alignment = Image.RIGHT_ALIGN;

            var pdfPCell = new PdfPCell(image)
            {
                Border = 0,
                HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
            };

            pdfPTable.AddCell(pdfPCell);

            document.Add(pdfPTable);
        }

        dynamicPdfBytes = dynamicPDfMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    byte[] pdfBytes;

    using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Documents/Test.pdf")))
    {
        using (var pdfMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfMemoryStream);

            var acroFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
            acroFields.SetField("TestField", "This is a test");
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            pdfStamper.Close();

            pdfBytes = pdfMemoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    var files = new List<byte[]> { dynamicPdfBytes, pdfBytes };

    byte[] array;

    using (var arrayMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);

        var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, arrayMemoryStream);

        document.Open();

        var directContent = pdfWriter.DirectContent;

        foreach (var bytes in files)
        {
            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(bytes);

            var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, arrayMemoryStream);
            pdfStamper.SetEncryption(null, _password, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);

            var numberOfPages = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;

            for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
            {
                document.NewPage();

                var page = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);

                directContent.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }

            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            pdfStamper.Close();
        }

        document.Close();

        array = arrayMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    memoryStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    return memoryStream;
}
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: It's a shame about some of the users on this site, instead of belittling a user for maybe not coding something to another's ideal or maybe not phrasing a question correctly, maybe users could be a little more helpful instead of obstructive, just a thought!

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566190/itext-merge-documents-with-acrofields for a `PdfCopy` example involving forms. This will also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582996/best-approach-to-use-pdfstamper-in-for-loop The `PdfCopy` object also has a `SetEncryption()` method as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719629/javascript-to-automatically-supply-password

Comment: Note that you are using an old version of iText. You really should upgrade to iText 7, because iText 5 (or earlier) are no longer supported. Please don't use the code you wrote in this question in production. If your customer sees your code, he might not be happy. If your customer doesn't see your code, please note that iText is licensed under the AGPL and that not sharing your code with your customer means that you'll need to purchase a commercial license for your use of iText.

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the most elegant of solutions, however it is a solution to this specific issue and I hope it proves useful to others.

The following code can be used in conjunction with the original sample code, simply comment out all `pdfStamper` references in the code above:

```
private MemoryStream SecureMemoryStream()
{
    var memoryStream = CreateMemoryStream();

    return GetSecureMemoryStream(memoryStream);
}

private MemoryStream GetSecureMemoryStream(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    byte[] array;

    using (var secureMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(memoryStream);

        using (var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, secureMemoryStream))
        {
            pdfStamper.SetEncryption(null, _password, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
        }

        array = secureMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    outputStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
    outputStream.Position = 0;

    return outputStream;
}
```

Comment: This isn't helpful. Your `GetSecureMemoryStream()` method encrypts a single PDF file (and for some readon it also flattens all form fields if any). The question is how to *merge* PDF files. As I tried to.explain in my comments, option 1 is to use `PdfCopy` (or `PdfSmartCopy`). Option 2 is to upgrade to iText 7 as the version of iText that is used by the OP is no longer supported.